# Mapping the values from a Map to a String in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures

I have a map like this:

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("Lit1" -> 8, "Lit2" -> 11, "Lit3" -> 7)
```

and a formula like this:

```
val r: String = "(Lit1 & (Lit2 | Lit3) & ~Lit2)"
```

how I can use the `map` to map the values for `Lit1`, `Lit2`, and `Lit3`, so that I will have the `r` string as

```
val r: String = "(8 & (11 | 7) & ~11)"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to parse the string `r` so that you can look up the values in the `map`. Then replace the lookedup keys with the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to find and replace the literals with the values you retrieve from the map:

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("Lit1" -> 8, "Lit2" -> 11, "Lit3" -> 7)
val r: String = "(Lit1 & (Lit2 | Lit3) & ~Lit2)"
val s: String = """Lit\d+""".r.replaceAllIn(r, m => map(m.group(0)).toString)


println(s) // (8 & (11 | 7) & ~11)
```

If it's possible that one or more literals are not present in the lookup map, you'd need to use `getOrElse`:

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("Lit1" -> 8, "Lit2" -> 11, "Lit3" -> 7)
val r: String = "(Lit1 & (Lit2 | Lit3) & ~Lit2 & Lit4)"
val s: String = """Lit\d+""".r.replaceAllIn(r, m => map.getOrElse(m.group(0), m.group(0)).toString)


println(s) // (8 & (11 | 7) & ~11 & Lit4)
```

Comment: Clever, but it throws if string `r` contains a "Lit" reference not found in the `Map`.

Comment: True. Would have to do some orElse-ing to handle that.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen , Thanks man for this. I was trying to find the general `.r` expression for the cases when the `LitX` is a concrete name, e.g., `Algorithm`, etc. And, I already faced the issue that @jwvh, has mentioned.

Comment: @user4712458 Yeah, I updated my answer to cover that case.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen, just for those that might need a general case for the `Lit`s names, like I am, the`.r` expression is: 
`val s: String = """[A-Za-z]+""".r.replaceAllIn(r, m => map.getOrElse(m.group(0), m.group(0)).toString)`

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want.

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("Lit1" -> 8, "Lit2" -> 11, "Lit3" -> 7)
val r: String = "(Lit1 & (Lit2 | Lit3) & ~Lit2)"

map.foldLeft(r){case (s, (k,v)) => s.replaceAll(k,v.toString)}
// res0: String = (8 & (11 | 7) & ~11)
```

Fold over the `Map` key->value pairs, modifying the `String` on each step.

Comment: Elegant +1. Might become expensive if the lookup map grows in size though.

Comment: @jwvh, Yep. It's really functional. I think I have to take it and to understand exactly how (and why :)) it's functioning. Thanks million times!

Comment: Breaks if there's a "Lit1" and "Lit11", though.

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul, I have concrete names instead of `Lit1` and `Lit2`, e.g., I have `Graph`, `Algorithm`, etc.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, ever the eagle eye. That situation could be handled by sorting the keys by string-length and replacing the longer strings first. An unfortunate complication but workable. Good catch.

Comment: @jwvh , As I can accept only one solution, I selected that one from @Robby Cornelissen , because I can continue to adapt it more easily in my case. What I mean is that each time that I use `foldLeft` and `foldRight` and `map` methods I think that - that's it! Now I understand them. - but then I fall on their trap again and again! Thanks so much for the alternative solution.

Comment: @user4712458 the problem is if one name is a substring of another, not just if it's LitNN. But the change jwh gives fixes that